# bool flag set to false even though XML Element Exists

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am using a bool flag to check to make sure XML Elements exist before writing them to a variable.

The problem is that I seem to be getting a false negative.  I know the element exits because I can see it in the XML sample.  However, the flag is still being set to false...

Code Example:

```
bool flag;

flag = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("statusCode");
if(flag)
{
   statusCode = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsInt();                                
}
else
{
   statusCode = 333;
}

flag = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("statusDesc");
if (flag)
{
   statusDesc = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
else
{
   statusDesc = "";
}
flag = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Guid");
if (flag)
{
   guid = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
else
{
   guid = "";
}
```

XML Example:

```
<statusCode>0</statusCode>
<statusDesc/>
<Status/>
<WSKey/>
<Priority/>
<Guid>3A336A97-BCA3-43F8-849C-A40D129B25AA</Guid>
```

statusCode resolves as true, statusDesc resolves as false, but Guid also resolves as false.

Any ideas?

Comment: is that the actual code?

Comment: Yes, that is copy and pasted directly from VS.

Comment: This code works for me.  I get back the Guid.

Comment: I don't get it... I know it should be setting flag to true, and I see not reason why it would be false.

Even worse, if I take the check out I get an exception... So for some reason it isn't finding the Guid Element.  I can see Guid in the variable holding the XML and everything...

The Status and WSKey elements should affect this at all should they? I would think "ReadToFollowing" would read over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result with you. here is the code

```
 class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + 
                "<root>" +
                "<statusCode>0</statusCode>" + 
                "<statusDesc/>" + 
                "<Status/>" + 
                "<WSKey/>" + 
                "<Priority/>" + 
                "<Guid>3A336A97-BCA3-43F8-849C-A40D129B25AA</Guid>" + 
                "</root>";
        var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(
            new MemoryStream(
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s), false));

        bool flag;
        Int32 statusCode;
        String statusDesc;
        String guid;

        flag = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("statusCode");
        if (flag) {
            statusCode = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
        } else {
            statusCode = 333;
        }

        flag = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("statusDesc");
        if (flag) {
            statusDesc = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        } else {
            statusDesc = "";
        }
        flag = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Guid");
        if (flag) {
            guid = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        } else {
            guid = "";
        }
    }
}
```

it seems that the method ReadToFollowing will return false if the element has empty value (e.g. statusDesc). Put a break point at line "flag = xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("statusDesc");" and run the program to that line, if you have a look at the variable xmlReader, its property 'EOF' has been set true. That means it has read to the end of xml. This will explain why it can't find the Guid value in the next call to ReadToFollowing.

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up just using XmlDoc and Nodes to get the data. Empty values are still present in nodes just NULL, so it works out.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using LINQ to XML.

The following code snippet worked in my test:

```
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument temp = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse("<root><statusCode>0</statusCode><statusDesc/><Status/><WSKey/><Priority/><Guid>3A336A97-BCA3-43F8-849C-A40D129B25AA</Guid></root>");
    var t = temp.Descendants("Guid").Any();
```

Regards,

Comment: I am actually reading from a large XML file...  I am just curious why the flag is getting set to false, because it shouldn't be.